# Ricci tensor for warped submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

In the setting that we have a Riemannian submersion under the $S^1$ action for $M=\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times S^{2n+1}$ with the metric $k(t) = -dt^2+\alpha^2(t)g + \beta^2(t)h$ where $g$ is the horizontal and $h$ the vertical part of the metric and $ds^{2n+1} = g+h$, I want to calculate the Ricci tensor. For simplicity I leave out all the terms that involve the vector field $\partial_t$.

I started with a ONB $\{E_\lambda\}$ of $(S^{2n+1},ds^{2n+1})$ where $g(E_i,E_i) = h(E_{2n+1},E_{2n+1})=1$, $i\neq2n+1$.

Now I used Koszul formula to calculate the Levi-civita connection. I got

$\nabla_{E_i} E_j = \nabla^{2n+1}_{E_i}E_j$

$\nabla_{E_i} E_{2n+1} = \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\nabla^{2n+1}_{E_i}E_{2n+1}$

$\nabla_{E_{2n+1}} E_{2n+1} = \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\nabla^{2n+1}_{E_{2n+1}}E_{2n+1}$

$\nabla_{E_{2n+1}} E_{i} = \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\mathscr{H}\nabla^{2n+1}_{E_{2n+1}}E_{i} + \mathscr{V}\nabla^{2n+1}_{E_{2n+1}}E_{i}$

Here $\mathscr{H}, \mathscr{V}$ denote the projections onto horizontal/vertical subspaces.

But now when I use these results to calculate the Ricci tensor, I get in trouble. For example, if I calculate

$k(\nabla_i\nabla_{j}E_j - \nabla_j\nabla_i E_j - \nabla_{[E_i,E_j]}E_j,E_i) 
\\= k(\nabla_i^{2n+1}\mathscr{H}\nabla_j^{2n+1}E_j - \nabla_j^{2n+1}\mathscr{H}\nabla_i^{2n+1}E_j - \nabla^{2n+1}_{\mathscr{H}[E_i,E_j]}E_j,E_i) + \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}k(\nabla_i^{2n+1}\mathscr{V}\nabla_j^{2n+1}E_j - \nabla_j^{2n+1}\mathscr{V}\nabla_i^{2n+1}E_j - \nabla^{2n+1}_{\mathscr{V}[E_i,E_j]}E_j,E_i)$

where I don't know how to simplify this.

Comment: After some further calculations I think the last term can be simplified a bit more to $-\beta^2h(\mathscr{V}[E_i,E_j],\mathscr{V}[E_i,E_j])$. But how do I get an explicit expression for this term?

Comment: Can I make the assumptions that $\mathscr{V}[E_i,E_j] = 0$ and $[E_i,E_{2n+1}] = 2E_{2n+1}$ ?

Comment: It's probably better to start with the case of a simple warped product, and deal with the splitting of the metric on $M$ after that. Iirc the computation of the curvature tensors of warped products is carried out in O'Niell's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry*.

Comment: Yes, I use Oneill as a reference as well. There is even a formula in the last corollary for the sectional curvature of a submersion. But I think I can't leave out the splitting because I want to calculate the submersion metric and therefore have to split the metric in a horizontal and vertical part or what do you mean by a simple warped product? For product metrics there are already results for warped metrics but I think a submersion is something different.